# How can I develop a custom AuthorizeAttribute that accepts a login OR a token?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, authorization, custom-attributes

In my MVC 5 application, I decorate my controllers as follows:

```
[Authorize]
public class Controller
{
  ..
```

However, one requirement I have is to use a token to authorize an action without going to the login screen. ie: `http://{website}/Action?token={/* token for this user */}`

Thus, **how can I develop a custom AuthorizeAttribute that accepts a login (default behavior) OR a token (custom, required behavior)?**

In other words, if I use `http://{website}/Action`, I would be redirected to the login screen (if I am not authorized), but if I use `http://{website}/Action?token={/* token for this user */}`, I would be authorized and redirected to said action.

---

`[TokenAuthorize]` class

```
public class TokenAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private const string SecureToken = "token";

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (Authorize(filterContext))
        {
            return;
        }

        HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
    }

    private bool Authorize(AuthorizationContext actionContext)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpRequestBase request = actionContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request;
            string token = request.Params[SecureToken];

            return SecurityManager.IsTokenValid(token);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

---

If I decorate my controllers with:

```
[Authorize]
[TokenAuthorize]
public class Controller
{
  ..
```

It is processed as `Authorize` AND `TokenAuthorize`<sub>[(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17272479)</sub>. I need to develop a way to process such as `Authorize` OR `TokenAuthorize`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shoe's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35185304) led me on the right track.

I implemented his suggestion and did the following in my `Authorize` function:

```
private bool Authorize(AuthorizationContext actionContext)
{
    try
    {
        HttpContextBase context = actionContext.RequestContext.HttpContext;
        string token = context.Request.Params[SecurityToken];

        bool isTokenAuthorized = SecurityManager.IsTokenValid(token);
        if (isTokenAuthorized) return true;

        bool isDefaultAuthorized = AuthorizeCore(context);
        return isDefaultAuthorized;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Decorating with just `[TokenAuthorize]`, I can authorize an action via login (default) OR via token.

Answer (score 2):

How about decorating with only `TokenAuthorize` and then falling back to the default behavior if no token exists?

**TokenAuthorize.cs**

```
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
    bool isTokenAuthorized = HasValidToken(...);
    if(isTokenAuthorized) return true;

    bool isDefaultAuthorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
    if(isDefaultAuthorized) return true;

    return false;
}
```

**MyController.cs**

```
[TokenAuthorize]
public class MyController
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Perfect Code: Validate token from DB

```
public class TokenAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    string _connectionString;

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (Authorize(filterContext))
        {
            return;
        }

        HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
    }


    protected bool Authorize(AuthorizationContext httpContext)
    {
        bool isTokenAuthorized = HasValidToken();
        if(isTokenAuthorized) return true;

        return false;
    }
    protected bool HasValidToken()
    {
        string token = string.Empty;
        token = HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["token"];
        _connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlTransaction txn = null;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            txn = conn.BeginTransaction();
            List<SqlParameter> parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
            SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter();
            parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@token", token));

            parameter = new SqlParameter("@return_ops", 0);
            parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            parameters.Add(parameter);

            SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(txn, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "[master_LoggedInUsers]", parameters.ToArray());

            int result = Convert.ToInt32(parameters[1].Value);

            if (result <= 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else return true;
        }
    }
}
```

[TokenAuthorize]
   public class MasterController : Controller
    {}